# Access VBA - Problems looping through fields in Access last record and exporting to Word bookmarks?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

Thanks for looking at this.

I have a recordset with 60 fields and I want to export the **last** record for each field into a Microsoft Word file with 60 bookmarks called `g1` to `g60`.

Of course I would like to loop through these but can't make it work.

Essentially what I want is this:

```
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim wDoct As Word.Document
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rng As Word.Range
Dim intI As Integer
Dim fld As DAO.field

Set wApp = New Word.Application
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Peter\Documents\testdoc.docm", ReadOnly:=False)
Set wDoct = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Peter\Documents\Trends.docx")
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Overall")

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Grades")

If Not rs.EOF Then rs.MoveLast

wDoc.Bookmarks("g1").Range.Text = Nz(rs!PlanQ, "")
wDoc.Bookmarks("g2").Range.Text = Nz(rs!PlanQMin, "")
wDoc.Bookmarks("g3").Range.Text = Nz(rs!PlanUnsat, "")
wDoc.Bookmarks("g4").Range.Text = Nz(rs!BriefQ, "")
wDoc.Bookmarks("g5").Range.Text = Nz(rs!BriefQmin, "")
wDoc.Bookmarks("g6").Range.Text = Nz(rs!BriefUnsat, "")
' and so on up to 60
wDoct.Save
wApp.Quit
```

This works but needs to be looped of course - I tried this, but it errors out:

```
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim wDoct As Word.Document
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rng As Word.Range
Dim intI As Integer
Dim fld As DAO.field

Set wApp = New Word.Application
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Peter\Documents\testdoc.docm", ReadOnly:=False)
Set wDoct = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Peter\Documents\Trends.docx")
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Overall")

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Grades")

If Not rs.EOF Then rs.MoveLast

intI = 1

With rs
Do Until .EOF
For Each fld in rs.Fields
wDoc.Bookmarks("g" & "intI").Range.Text = Nz(rs!fld.Name, "")

Next fld
intI = intI + 1
loop
End With

wDoct.save
Wapp.quit
```

Any ideas will be very much welcome, otherwise I have a lot of typing ahead of me. :-)

Thank you for your time!

Peter

This is the current code that fail like mentioned below:
**UPDATE** This is the exact copy paste.

```
Public Sub Looptest()

Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim index As Integer
Dim item As Variant

Set wApp = New Word.Application
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Peter\Documents\testdoc.docm", ReadOnly:=False)

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Grades")

If Not rs.EOF Then rs.MoveLast

For Each item In rs.Fields
    index = index + 1

    Dim bookmarkName As String
    bookmarkName = "g" & index

    Dim bookmarkValue As Variant
    bookmarkValue = Nz(rs(item.Name).Value, "")

    Debug.Print "Try set bookmark '" & bookmarkName & "' to '" & bookmarkValue & "' now."

    Dim bookmarkRange As Word.Range
    Set bookmarkRange = wDoc.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range

    bookmarkRange.Text = bookmarkValue

    Set bookmarkRange = Nothing
    Next item

wApp.DisplayAlerts = False
wDoc.SaveAs2 "C:\Users\Peter\Documents\" & rs!ID & "_gradesheet.docm"
wDoc.Close
wApp.Quit
```

Comment: You really need to remove everything from your code that doesn't belong there (leftover variables etc.). And use `Option Explicit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be what you want:

```vb
Dim index As Integer
Dim item As Variant

For Each item In rs.Fields
    index = index + 1
    wDoc.Bookmarks("g" & index).Range.Text = Nz(rs(item.Name).Value, "")
Next item
```

It iterates the fields of the recordset and fills the bookmarks like you seem to want it.

What exactly error did you receive?

You should also check your code again, there are some superfluous fragments in it.

## Update:

You get this error as I understand:

> 5941: The requested member of the collection does not exist.

Try this instead. It separates the functionality to single steps, enabling you to determine what the cause is:

- It builds the new bookmark name
- It retrieves the value to set to the bookmark
- It prints out which bookmark now will be set to which value
- It gets a reference to the bookmark to be set
- It sets the bookmarks value

You should be able now to find out the reason for the error, by seeing which line of code breaks and what the values of the variables are.

```vb
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim item As Variant

    For Each item In rs.Fields
        If item.Name <> "ID" Then
            index = index + 1

            If index = 127 Then Exit For

            Dim bookmarkName As String
            bookmarkName = "g" & index

            Dim bookmarkValue As Variant
            bookmarkValue = Nz(rs(item.Name).Value, "")

            Debug.Print "Try set bookmark '" & bookmarkName & "' to '" & bookmarkValue & "' now."

            Dim bookmarkRange As Word.Range
            Set bookmarkRange = wDoc.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range

            bookmarkRange.Text = bookmarkValue

            Set bookmarkRange = Nothing
        End If
    Next item
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately I get "the requested member of the collection does not exist" on the wDoc.Bookmarks...... line. The bookmarks are valid and if I manually type it out, it works (g1,g2,etc). Any other ideas?

Comment: All of them exist?

Comment: Do you mean references? I've got MS office excel and word 14.0 object library an Ms access 14.0 database engine object.

Comment: No, why do you expect I'm talking about project references? I meant if you are sure that **all** of the necessary bookmarks exist. You could find that out by debugging. But I updated the answer, please take a look. It should help you digging out the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that - I'm just new to some of the terms. Isolating the issue was a good idea. Error 5941 now appears at this line: Set bookmarkRange = wDoc.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range . I have just quadrouple checked the bookmarks and they exist. And typing it manually like: wDoc.Bookmarks("g1").Range.Text = Nz(rs!PlanQ, "") , works without error. If the bookmark didn't exist I would expect an error here I guess?

Comment: What was printed out to the direct box by the `Debug.Print` just before the error occurs? Must be something beginning with `Try set bookmark`. Additionally you may also check the value of `bookmarkName` when the error occurs. And are you sure that you use the correct document? You have two of them in your sample (`wApp` (`C:\Users\Peter\Documents\testdoc.docm`) and `wDoct` (`C:\Users\Peter\Documents\Trends.docx`) ). Maybe you mix something up?

Comment: About your latest added sample in your question: 1: `rs` is set twice (`Overall` and then `Grades`). Maybe in `Grades` there are more fields like existing bookmarks in the word document? 2: You set the variable `wDoct` but then you use `wDoc` instead.

Comment: All understood. Initially this was part of a larger set of code where I was exporting to 2 docs and 1 excel. In order to isolate the issue if have made a test only comprising the mentioned code (post updated above). With regard to the immediate window and debug.print I think it gives the answer (just don't now how to solve it). I have 126 bookmarks in the wDoc file - the debug window speeds through g1-126 and errors (5941) when it tries 127 (which doesn't exist). How to stop it at 126?

Comment: After `index = Index + 1` add this line of code: `If index = 127 Then Exit For`.

Comment: Yes! Now it's working:-) Only issue is that it starts with the "ID" field instead of the first "real" field in the database.

Comment: I updated my last sample once more to fit your needs, it now omits the `ID` field. Also please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find that it solved your problem.

Comment: Perfect! It works - thank you very much for your extensive help. I have learned a lot through this:-) Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your code tries to match numbered bookmarks to table fields, based only on their order. Even if you get it to work now, this will be very hard to maintain, every change will cause new troubles.

It is much easier to name the bookmarks identical to their matching table field names, i.e. `PlanQ` etc.

Then your code becomes simpler and maintainable.
And if a table field (e.g. `ID`) doesn't exist as bookmark in the document, you can simply ignore it.

```
For Each fld In rs.Fields

    Dim bookmarkName As String
    bookmarkName = fld.Name

    Dim bookmarkValue As String  ' since you are using Nz(), you don't need Variant
    bookmarkValue = Nz(fld.Value, "")

    If wDoc.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmarkName) Then
        wDoc.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range.Text = bookmarkValue
    Else
        Debug.Print "Ignored table field <" & bookmarkName & "> - no matching bookmark found in word document."
    End If

Next item
```

Comment: Thanks for this! You are right - this I very flexible and maintanable. I shall implement it in version 1.1 :-)

Comment: You could also think about using custom document properties (or variables) instead of bookmarks. These can be referenced in the document also. You should read a bit about their usage.